# How to shorten the height of ColSideColors in heatmap.2()

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

My following code:

```
library(gplots);
library(RColorBrewer);

dat <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wM7WxEvY",sep="\t",na.strings="NA",header=TRUE)
dat <- dat[complete.cases(dat),]
dat.log <- log2(dat);

# Clustering and distance function
hclustfunc <- function(x) hclust(x, method="ward")
distfunc <- function(x) dist(x,method="maximum")

# Here we cluster based on the Celltype (Column)
d <- distfunc(t(dat.log))
fit <- hclustfunc(d)
clusters <- cutree(fit, h=20)
nofclust.height <-  length(unique(as.vector(clusters)));


# Colors setting 
hmcols <- rev(redblue(256));
selcol <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Set1"))
clustcol.height = selcol(nofclust.height);


pdf(file="temp.pdf",width=30,height=40);
heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat.log),Colv=FALSE,lhei = c(0.25,4),ColSideColors=clustcol.height[clusters],density.info="none",scale="none",margin=c(10,10),col=hmcols,symkey=F,trace="none",dendrogram="none",keysize=1,hclust=hclustfunc,distfun=distfunc);
dev.off();
```

Generate this figure:
[image]

Note that the `ColSideColors` is too high. How can shorten it?

Answer (score 2):

`?heatmap.2`: The layout for the `RowSideColor` and `ColSideColor` "can be overriden by specifiying appropriate values for lmat, lwid, and lhei. `lmat` controls the relative position of each element, while `lwid` controls the column width, and `lhei` controls the row height. See the help page for [layout](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/layout.html) for details on how to use these arguments."

In your case, you have to change the lhei, try `lhei=c(1,15)`

Comment: You could be a bit more specific than citing the package documentation. If you pay attention to the OP, the `lhei` is already used in there. What does the arguments 1 and 15 do, for example? blatantly changing the line height also generates error messages a lá: `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`